# SQL query to extract number of dates in the same month

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to write a SQL command that selects from database the number of rows in which the date has the same year and month as this year and month.

For example: it's July 2020 now, so I want the command to extract the no. of rows in which the dates lie in July 2020.

From what I have understood on the other answers from Stackoverflow, I wrote this C# code:

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(date) FROM ordertbl WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE())", con);

 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 dr.Read();

 lblthismonth.Text = dr[0].ToString();
 dr.Close();
```

The column with the date is called `date`.

Comment: What problem are you having with you code?

Comment: And? What happens when you run this?

Comment: Does this work?  Have you tried it and got results you weren't expecting?  What's your question?

Comment: I'm sorry all of you. I just realised that I Didnt have a record within the same month.  I'm Sorry to be careless. But I think I should keep the answer for those who have this same doubt.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(date)` returns a scalar, not a set. You should use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar), not `ExecuteReader`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better not to manipulate your table data. Search a calculated range instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(date)
FROM ordertbl 
WHERE 
  date >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)) AS DATE) and
  date < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())) AS DATE)
```

With your query, if you have a million rows, and 100,000 of them match, sqlserver must do 2 million date operations to extract the year and month from the million dates, and then 2 million comparisons comparing the extracted numbers. An index can not be used

If you work out a date range, and the column is indexed, then sqlserver can use the indexed data because it isn't being manipulated, and know which 100,000 rows to retrieve. In the case of a Count like this it doesn't even need to hit the table; it can just count the index

Typically we should always try to avoid putting a function call on the left hand side of a comparison operator in a WHERE clause